# python: recursive lambda expression

Tags: python, recursion, functional-programming

I'm following a book "functional python programming" by David Mertz, i have come across a following piece of code.

```
def echo_IMP():
    while 1:
        x = raw_input("IMP -- ")
        if x == 'quit':
            break
        else:
            print(x)
```

The functional version of above code seems like this:

```
def identity_print(x):
    print(x)
    return x


echo_FP = lambda: identity_print(raw_input("IMP -- "))=='quit' or echo_FP()
echo_FP()
```

How this `identity_print()` is being called again ?

what does this `or` expression actually doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo_FP = lambda: identity_print(raw_input("IMP -- "))=='quit' or echo_FP()
```

The order of execution is:

1. `raw_input("IMP -- ")` returns users input (let's call in `input`)
2. result of raw input goes to `identity_print(input)` - which prints `input` and returns it
3. the remainder of the function is `input=='quit' or echo_FP()`. The way `A or B` works is:

   `if A:
       return A
   else:
       return B`

   So, if `input=='quit'` (that is `A`), it returns True and ends there, otherwise the whole lambda is executed again (`echo_FP()`).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a function with some conditions inside it. in other words, you are saying "call identity_print, and if the result is 'quit': the condition is validated, if not: call me again"

The `echo_FP` function:

```
echo_FP = lambda: identity_print(raw_input("IMP -- "))=='quit' or echo_FP()
```

has this kind of behavior:

```
def echo_FP():

    var = identity_print(input("IMP -- "))

    if var == 'quit':
        pass
    else:
        echo_FP()
```

The recursion comes when `identity_print` doesn't returns `quit` because the function executes the `or` condition which is a call to `echo_FP`

Answer (score 0):

Here we are defining one lambda function with no actual input but the statement is actually a function call to *identity_print()* ..whose input is entered by user. That is why we are calling it like this *echo_FP()* with no input.

As per the functionaliy of 'or' operator it will search for first right match. so in this case if user enters anything other than 'quit' then the first match fails (*identity_print(raw_input("IMP -- "))=='quit* will result False) so it goes and executes *echo_FP()*. so till the point user keeps on entering anything other than 'quit' , it will keep on calling *echo_FP()*. The moment you enter 'quit' it will return true and comes out of it.

[image]